# Is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^m=S_3(n)\cdot\dfrac{P_{m-3}(n)}{N_m}$ for odd $m>1,\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^m=S_2(n)\cdot\dfrac{P_{m-2}'(n)}{N_m}$ for even $m$?

Tags: polynomials, sequences-and-series, infinite-sequences

I asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828000/conjecture-sum-limits-k-1nki-s-3n-times-fracp-i-3nn-i-for-odd)

---

When I was in high school, I was fascinated by
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$ so I tried to find the general value of the sum
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m\;\text{ for all }\; m \in \mathbb{N}
$$
I was able to to find the sum up to $m=6$.  Here, I tried to search for a pattern to find the general solution of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m $ s.t $m \in \mathbb{N}$ which I failed to do, but I noticed this pattern:
$$
\begin{align}
S_1(n) & :={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\\
S_2(n) & :={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2= \color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}}}\\
S_3(n) & :={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^3= \color{red}{\frac{\color{red}{n^2(n+1)^2}}{\color{red}{4}}}}\\
S_4(n) & :={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^4=\color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}} \cdot \frac{3n^2+3n-1}{  5}}\\
S_5(n) & :={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^5= \color{red}{\frac{\color{red}{n^2(n+1)^2}}{\color{red}{4}}} \cdot\frac{2n^2+2n-1}{ 3}}\\
S_6(n) & :={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^6= \color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}} \cdot \frac{3n^4+6n^3-3n+1}{ 7 }}\\
S_7(n) & :={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^7= \color{red}{\frac{\color{red}{n^2(n+1)^2}}{\color{red}{4}} }\cdot\frac{3n^4+6n^3-n^2-4n+2}{ 6}}\\
S_8(n) &:= {\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^8= \color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}} \cdot \frac{5n^6+15n^5+5n^4-15n^3-n^2+9n+3}{ 15}}\\
S_9(n) &:= {\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^9= \color{red}{\frac{\color{red}{n^2(n+1)^2}}{\color{red}{4}}} \cdot\frac{(n^2+n-1)(2n^4 +4n^3-n^3-3n^2+3)}{ 5}}\\
S_{10}(n) & := {\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{10}= \color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}} \cdot \frac{ 3 n^8+ 12 n^7+ 8 n^6 - 18 n^5- 10 n^4+ 24 n^3   + 2 n^2 - 15 n +5}{ 11}}\\
S_{11}(n) & :={\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{11}= \color{red}{\frac{\color{red}{n^2(n+1)^2}}{\color{red}{4}}} \cdot\frac{2n^8 +8n^7+4n^6-16n^5-5n^4+26n^3-3n^2-20n+10}{ 6}}
\end{align}
$$
I noticed that:

- For odd $m>1$,
  $$
  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m= \color{red}{\frac{{n^2(n+1)^2}}{{4}}} \cdot \frac{P_{m-3}(n)}{N_m}
  $$ s.t $P_{m-3}(n)$ is an $m-3$ polynomial with integer coefficients $ \{a_{m-3},\ldots a_1,a_0 \}$ such that $\gcd \{a_{m-3},\ldots a_1,a_0 \}=1$, $N_m\in \mathbb {N}$.
- For even $m$,
  $$
  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m= \color{blue}{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}}\cdot \frac{P_{m-2}'(n)}{N_m}
  $$ s.t $P_{m-2}'(n)$ is an $m-2$ polynomial with integer coefficients $\{ a_{m-2},\dots a_1,a_0 \}$ such that $\gcd \{ a_{m-2},\dots a_1,a_0 \}=1$, $N_m\in \mathbb {N}$.

When I was in high school I couldn't prove this pattern, and I  remembered  this observation that I had totally forgotten about. Now, after two years from my first attempt, I tried to prove this pattern again, but I couldn't.

---

This question has been partly answered  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444681/maybe-faulhaber-polynomial-s-kx-0-have-only-rational-roots-0-frac12) (The answer shows that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m$ is divisible by ${n^2(n+1)^2}$ for odd $m>1$ and
$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m$ is divisible by ${n(2n+1)(n+1)}$ for even $m$) the only missing part is to show that the denominator is a multiple of $4$ if $m\in 2\mathbb{N}+1$, and the denominator is a multiple of   $6$  if $m \in 2\mathbb{N}$.

---

**Update** With the help of the paper that @SamHopkins recommended I posted an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4833907/1132763)

Comment: @SamHopkins I couldn't prove that pattern from Faulhaber's formula.

Comment: @SamHopkins somehow I forgot to write that $gcd \{ a_0 , a_1,\dots, a_i\} =1$

Comment: Denominators of Faulhaber polynomials are studied in the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03857. It should contain an answer to your question.

Comment: @SamHopkins Are you sure that it contain an answer to my question ?after a quick look at it I didn't find anything about my question.

Comment: @SamHopkins I didn't understand how this would help with my question, it took me a loot of time to semi understand that theorem.

Comment: @pie the paper in question answers completely your question. It gives you that $d_n=(n+1)q_n$ and theorem 3 shows you the exact factorization of $q_n$. It suffices to notice that $\epsilon_2=1$ when $n$ is odd $\geq 3$ which is the case, and compute $\epsilon_3$ for $n$ even for which the formula is given, it actually equals $1$ most of the time

Comment: @Elaqqad Thank you for your explanations and thank you   
Sam Hopkins for the paper and explanation


btw should I edit the question on MSE and include the answer or should I write that on answer or what ?


should I delete this question?

Comment: @SamHopkins the only question on my mind now is how did you find this paper

Comment: I googled “denominators of Faulhaber polynomials.” Anyways I think the question is better for MSE. You should post the answer there.